# Cannot get 5GHz Networks to appear in Kali Linux (Panda Wireless PAU09)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I run a virtualized copy of Kali Linux on my MacBook Pro and I am trying to use my Panda Wireless PAU09. It is a recommended card and is said to be "Plug and Play" without having to install drivers or configuring it, but this has not been the case for me.

I can run `iwconfig`, `lsusb`, and `dmesg`, and all of them display the same thing:

`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:5572 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5572 Wireless Adapter`

However, after I looked deeper into `dmesg` it shows that it is loading the firmware, *`rt2800usb`* and *`rt2870.bin`* being loaded and they are able to activate successfully.

I still cannot see any wireless networks; the device is detected but the networks are not.

When i run `dmesg` twice, an error pops up and says:

`IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready`

I have installed any driver that I can get my hands on, I have contacted panda and they gave me a "Linux" driver which ended up being corrupt and dysfunctional.

I've also added a few blacklisted sources to aid the drivers and this was recommended by a few people, and after doing so my WiFi shows up for a few seconds then goes away.

The sources are for the Ralink driver family:

`http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease`

and `http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian Strech InRelease`

Comment: I have a similar problem on Ubuntu: the driver for my BroadCom WiFi card supports only 2.4 GHz, though booting Windows on the same machine finds both frequency ranges. I have learned to live with the lower frequency network.

Comment: I was able to install the mac divers and I can see both 2.4 and 5ghz networks and connect to them just fine but, when i use it in my vm with kali i cant see my home networks either with 2.4or 5ghz and i'm not sure why. I also changed the country code on my adapter to match my own.

Comment: Is Kali seeing the actual harware, or a virtualized adapter?

Comment: How can I check?